# Grabar documento en una unidad de red

Tags: visual-foxpro

He creado una función donde se crea un objeto excel y en el le agrego información de una tabla de la base de datos al final trato de grabarlo o guardarlo en la unidad de red con"

```
lcNombreArchivo = "\\192.168.1.4\Documentos\prueba.xls"

local excel
excel = createobject("Excel.Application")
...
...
...
...
...
excel.ActiveWorkBook.SaveAs(lcNombreArchivo,1)
```

pero cuando se ejecuta me sale un error donde no se puede obtener la propiedad SaveAs en la clase Workbook.

**Que otra opción hay para poder grabar el objeto excel?** ya que si pongo la unidad `C:\` envés de la IP no me sale algún error y si se llega a grabar el mismo.